# Проблемы получения нужного среза на разных итерациях

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке разбить данные для записи, в случае, если количество символов в записи >= количеству файлов для записи - все отрабатывается нормально. Но если символов меньше, то запись идет криво, то символ пропадет, то лишние пустые файлы появятся. Перепробовал различные варианты, без результата.

```
p = bytearray(invert_sequence())

# automatically append symbol in flow need to rewrite
if servers >= len(invert_sequence()):
    p = bytearray(invert_sequence())
    more_bytes = servers - len((invert_sequence()))
    p.extend(more_bytes * b"0")
    print("содержимое more_bytes", more_bytes)


def choice():
    if servers >= len(invert_sequence()):
        ch = p
    else:
        ch = invert_sequence()
    return ch

def shear():
    section = round(len(encrypt()) / servers)
    return section

for i in range(servers):  # подходит, только если серверов >= символов, и если символы // на сервера
    print(choice()[(i * shear()):((i * shear()) + (shear()))])

# write to file
for i in range(servers):
    with open(f"{uuid.uuid4()}.txt", "wb") as file0:
        file0.write(choice()[(i * shear()):((i * shear()) + (shear()))])
        file0.close()
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Почему вы не используете фиксированный размер записи и фиксированное сообщение, а вычисляете его каждый раз через функцию, ведь насколько я вижу вы никак не изменяете это сообщение во время записи в файлы?

Comment: Фиксированный размер сообщения не подходит из-за того, что количество файл-серверов может и будет разным(от 3 до бесконечности), поэтому создать фиксированный срез на n-элементов не получиться.

Comment: Под фиксированным я подразумеваю вычисленный один раз перед записью в какую-то переменную. Вообще для решения вашей проблемы я бы рекомендовал вам просто дополнять сообщение пробелами или какими-то символами заглушками до длины, кратной количеству серверов, после чего "резать"  сообщение уже на равные куски. В ином случае смените round() на math.ceil() в shear() и проверьте, исправилась ли ошибка.

Comment: В качестве заглушек для добивание длины файла используются нули.  Math.ceil частично помог, по прежнему создаются лишние пустые файла, но теперь как минимум загружает все данные.

Comment: Если вы хотите не создавать пустые файлы, то можете поставить условие на ненулевую длину среза, или перед самим вводом отдельно обрабатывать сообщения с длиной меньшей количества серверов, записывая в каждый по одному символу, пока эти символы не кончатся